# ASP.NET Storing data to container class

Tags: c#, asp.net

The problem is that when I read data from txt file with button_1 I place it in container class. When I want to print container data with button_2 in web site -container becoming empty. So the question is how to store data into container class?

Container:

```js
public class Matrix
{
    public int[,] matrix;

 public Matrix()
 {
        matrix = new int[6, 6];
 }

    public void AddNumber(int numb, int i, int j)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = numb;
    }
}
```

Web form:

```html
public partial class Forma : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Start_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[] separators = {' ', '\n', '\r', '\t'};

        int numb = 0;
        int Counter = 0; 

        if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Nepasirinkote failo!";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = string.Empty;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string[] allNumbers = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    numb = int.Parse(allNumbers[Counter]);
                    Counter++;
                    m.AddNumber(numb, i, j);
                }
            }
            Label1.Text = m.matrix[0, 5].ToString();
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = m.matrix[0, 5].ToString(); //Container infroamtion dissapears
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "container"? Please post some code as well so we can see what you have.

Comment: Here you go :) added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to a SmartClient application, a web application creates a new instance of your page class for each request. So the code

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
```

is called whenever you call the page or a postback occurs. So there is a new instance of the matrix and the previous one is gone the moment the first request ends.

There are some methods to store data between requests, each with their ups and downs:

- You can store the data in ViewState. Be aware that the ViewState is transferred to the client and sent back to the server, so you only want to do this with small amounts of data.
- You can store the data in Session cache. This can reduce the amount of users your application can handle per server because for each user the memory is allocated. Also, if you have a multi-server environment (Web farm), you need to make sure that each server can access the Session cache because a new request can usually be handled by a different server.
- The common pattern that is used with database data is to re-read data for the new request. As you get the file by upload, you could store the data in a database when receiving the file and re-read from the database. You'd need to make sure that you purge the data in the database in case it is not needed permanently.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) provides an overview of the various state management methods that are available in ASP.NET WebForms. Be aware that some of them are user-specific whereas others are shared by all users.